# How to fill fields in Zoho CRM automaticly

Tags: crm, zoho

I have this situation:
I have custom button in Zoho CRM where I want to create new Account. When I click the button, it opens page of my Zoho Creator Form, then I fill in this form and click submit. What I want to acomplish is that when I submit the form, I want some information from that form to be filled in CRM creation Account. I was thinking about using url. For example in Zoho Creator If I extend base url of my Form and finish url by e.g.`?text_field=abcd` when I go to that URL, the field "text_field" is filled with "abcd", but when I try to use the same mechanism, it wont work on CRM. is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In CRM, there is no option to fillup data on load. on the success you can write a function or using feild update you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that would get called on your form submission.
Extract the values from your creator form, then do
Zoho.crm.createRecord() if you want to create record or zoho.crm.updaterecord, with update record you'll have to provide a record ID.

If you only want to create a record its pretty straightforward, read about zoho.crm.createRecord()

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question it is not possible to achieve the same functionality in CRM. Although what you can try to do us use

1. create record using zoho.crm.createRecord
2. On successful creation redirect to CRM Accounts Edit page.(using /edit it depends on your CRM and the layout id's )

record is created first and than user has prefilled information
If user wants to add extra information than they can add and save the record